# Toggle input fields based on select value - jQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery

So I have the following input fields, which by default are hidden.

When the user selects an industry, the corresponding field should be visible. Of course, if the selection changes, the previous field should toggle back to hidden, and the new selection toggled to show.

I understand I could just have a conditional inside the jquery that toggles the input i.e.

```
if(selection == "SaaS") {
   $("#SaaSMeetings").show();
}
```

However, I am not sure how I can get the fields to toggle on each "change" event, based on the dropdown select.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**HTML**

```
<label for="">Industry?</label>
    <select id="industry">
        <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
        <option value="Media">Media/Advertising</option>
        <option value="SaaS">SaaS</option>
        <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
        <option value="Automobile">Automobile</option>
    </select>

<!-- Show Metric Input based on Industry Selection -->

<input type="text" id="telesalesCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="SaaSMeetings"  placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="MediaMeetings" placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
```

**The javascript:**

```
$('#industry').on('change',function(){

  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);

  //TODO: Show the input field based on this selection, and on each change, make sure the correct field is displayed.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toggle()` with argument to make show hide decision:

```
 $("#SaaSMeetings").toggle($(this).val()=="SaaS");
```

**complete code:**

```
$('#industry').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#SaaSMeetings").toggle($(this).val()=="SaaS");
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Will accept as soon as I can !

Answer (score 1):

Just hide everything and just show the one which is selected.

```
$('#industry').on('change',function(){
   var elms = $('[placeholder^=How]');
   elms.hide().filter(function(){
       return this.id.toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) > -1;
   }).show();
});
```

We have used `$.fn.filter` to filter the element and then we show it, while the rest are already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

use a switch statement, or change your select option values to match your input ids;

```
<option value="telesalesCalls">Telesales</option>
<input class="myInput" id="telesalesCalls" />

$('#industry').on('change',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val(); 
    console.log("Detected change..." + selection);

    $(".myInput").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#" + selection).show();
});
```

this is the longer switch way:

```
switch(selection){
    case "Telesales":
        $("#telesalesCalls").show();
        $("#SaaSMeetings").hide();
        $("#MediaMeetings").hide();
        $("#InsuranceCalls").hide();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use data attributes on the input fields, to indicate which value in the select element it should be visible for.

### Html

```
<label for="">Industry?</label>
    <select id="industry">
        <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
        <option value="Media">Media/Advertising</option>
        <option value="SaaS">SaaS</option>
        <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
        <option value="Automobile">Automobile</option>
    </select>

<!-- Show Metric Input based on Industry Selection -->

<input type="text" data-valueref="Telesales" id="telesalesCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" data-valueref="SaaS" id="SaaSMeetings"  placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" data-valueref="Media" id="MediaMeetings" placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" data-valueref="Insurance" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
```

### Javascript

```
$('#industry').on('change',function(){
  // get the selected value
  var selection = $(this).val();
  // get all input fields that has a valueref attribute containing the selected value, and show them
  var showinputs = $('input[data-valueref~="' + selection + '"]').show();
  // hide all other input fields
  $('input').not(showinputs).hide();
});
```

This approach would infact allow you to have a single input visible for multiple values. The following would display when SaaS or Insurance is selected

```
<input type="text" data-valueref="SaaS Insurance" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
```

It might be a good idea to filter the input fields using an extra class, to avoid affecting other input fields on the same page.

```
<input type="text" data-valueref="Insurance" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" class="valueref" style="display:none">
```

-

```
var showinputs = $('input.valueref[data-valueref~="' + selection + '"]').show();
$('input.valueref').not(showinputs).hide();
```